# How to calculate the work done in moving a charge inside an eletric field between two oppositely charged plates?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, electric-fields, work, conventions

[image]

As title says I'm having trouble trying to figure how to calculate the work done in moving the charge. This is an exercise from the book "Physics for Computer Science Students" chapter 14. I didn't understand the book's explanation about work done in moving a charge. Any help would be highly appreciate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The work done moving a charge is given by the distance moved along the direction of the electric field multiplied by the charge and the field strength.  In equation form it is $W = q*E*L$ where L in this case is the distance along the E-field direction, or the component of the motion that is along the E-field direction.  For your cases above, note that only the vertical motion will require work.  If you move horizontally, you are not moving against the field, so won't require work.  In the case of the diagonal, only the vertical component factors into computing the work.  Therefore, all three paths have the same vertical displacement (i.e. along the direction of the E-field which is 0.5 meters in each case), so have the same work.  I hope this helps.